# GroupBy of Anonymous Object strange result

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I am getting an unexpected result from GroupBy in this case, I expect a `Dictionary<string,List<object>>` from `GroupBy`. But the browser receives something like: `[{playdate, experiencetype...}, { ... }, { }], [{playdate, experiencetype,... }, { } ]`,...

So there are no Keys even though the objects *are* grouped into arrays, but I want Keys to be there. I put up a breakpoint and checked `packagedAjax`, and there seems to be a `GroupedEnumerable` there containing Lookups. Any thoughts?

```
var packagedAjax = showtimesByMovieAndLocation
                .Select(x =>
                        new
                        {
                            playdate = x.PlayDate,
                            experiencetype = x.FFCode,
                            vistasessionid = x.SessionID,
                            areacode = x.AreaCode
                        })
                .GroupBy(x => x.experiencetype);
return new JsonpResult(packagedAjax, Request.QueryString["callback"]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`GroupBy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534304(v=vs.110).aspx) returns an [`IGrouping`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb344977%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), not a Dictionary. If you want a Dictionary, convert it using [`.ToDictionary()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
var packagedAjax = showtimesByMovieAndLocation
            .Select(x =>
                    new
                    {
                        playdate = x.PlayDate,
                        experiencetype = x.FFCode,
                        vistasessionid = x.SessionID,
                        areacode = x.AreaCode
                    })
            .GroupBy(x => x.experiencetype)
            .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToList());
```